# sticky element breaking out of container

Tags: jquery, sticky

I'm using the stick em jquery library and trying to make my woocommerce single product summary sticky. However it keeps breaking out of the container and I just can't seem to figure out why.

It seems to need the related products too, otherwise it doesn't work, as I've tried to move the related products out of the sticky container to keep this separate.

This is what I have:

```
<div class='large-12 cell prodcontainer'>
 <div id="product-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php wc_product_class( 'stickem-container', $product ); ?>>
<div class="summary entry-summary stickem">
// stuff here

</div>
```

```
.prodcontainer {
   .stickem-container {
     position: relative;
     // .related { display: none; }
   }
   .stickit {
      position: fixed;
      top: 160px;
      width: 20%;
      right: 10%;
      width: 23% !important;
   }
   .stickit-end {
      bottom: 0px;
      position: absolute;
      right: 10%;
      width: 23% !important;
   }
}
```

$('.prodcontainer').stickem();

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

http://devsites-co-uk.stackstaging.com/typhoon/shop/typhoon-leisure/wetsuits-typhoon-leisure/men-wetsuits-typhoon-leisure/kona-gbs-bz-3mm-black-and-copper/

Comment: I cannot see the issue on the linked page.

Comment: It's breaking out of the container it shouldn't be going over the related products.